# A random generator with non-repeating elements and changing range

Tags: python, oop, random

I want to implement a random generator so that it is able to generate random number from 0 to n, but unless the range is exhausted, it should not return elements that has been returned. e.g. if the range is from 0 to 7, and the previous generation is 4, then 4 will not appear in the random generation until all integers in 0-7 are returned. Here is what I have so far - I swap the generated element to the front of the array and shrink the range.

Now I have to implement a function to change the range of the random generation while generating and the non-repeat condition still holds after the range has been changed. The function take a lower and upper bound, which indicates the new range and can be less or more than the old range. For example after 4 is returned, I change the range to 2 to 7, then 4 will not appear in the generation after the list 2-7 is exhausted.

I don't know what is the most efficient way of doing so. I tried to make a blacklist and regenerate an array in the range with numbers that are not in the blacklist, but I am having some problems with resetting the array after the list is exhausted.

```
class RandomGenerator:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.start = 0
        self.arr = list(range(n+1))
        
    def generate(self):
        if self.start > self.n:
            self.arr = list(range(n+1))
        
        r = random.randint(self.start, self.n)
        out = self.arr[r]
        
        temp = self.arr[self.start]
        self.arr[self.start] = self.arr[r]
        self.arr[r] = temp
        
        self.start += 1
        
        return out
```

Edit: Here I implement a change range function by the means of a blacklist. I'm not sure if it is a valid solution but it is definitely not efficient since I generate a new array every time I call the function generate. I don't know how I can use the original method of swapping elements or if it is possible.

```
import random


class RandomGenerator():
    def __init__(self, lower, upper):
        self.lower = lower
        self.upper = upper
        self.arr = list(range(lower, upper+1))
        self.blacklist = []
    def generate(self):
        if not self.arr:
            self.arr = list(range(self.lower, self.upper+1))
            
        n = len(self.arr)-1
        r = random.randint(0, n)
        out = self.arr[r]
        self.blacklist.append(out)
        self.arr = [x for x in self.arr if x not in self.blacklist]
        
        return out
        
    def change_range(self, lower, upper):
        self.lower = lower
        self.upper = upper


gen = RandomGenerator(4, 7)
print(gen.generate())
print(gen.generate())
print(gen.generate())
print(gen.generate())
print(gen.generate())
gen.change_range(2, 7)
print(gen.generate())
print(gen.generate())
print(gen.generate())
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your intention is with the resetting logic. Are you just trying to reset to where you started, or is the range of possible numbers supposed to grow? It's also a bit awkward to be calling this a "generator" since that's the name of a specific thing in Python, and you're not using it.

Comment: I need to reset to the new range, the new range can be smaller the original range since it is supposed to take a upper and lower bound

Comment: But how is the new range determined? There's no opportunity for new parameters to be set, since the user is just calling `generate()` and expecting a new value from it.

Comment: the new range is inputted. I need to add another function change_range() to the class, so then for example I can call RandomGenerator.change_range(2, 6) to set the new range

Comment: We can't troubleshoot code you haven't shown us, so if there's more to your API, you *really* need to include it in the question or it's not going to be part of our answers.

Comment: Okay I edited the post and implemented a change range function.

Answer (score 0):

For small `n`, you could generate a list of numbers, randomly `shuffle` it, then `pop` elements out of it; when it is exhausted, generate a new `source`, and repeat.

```
import random


def get_random_without_repeats(n=8):
    source = []
    while True:
        if not source:
            source = list(range(n))
            random.shuffle(source)
        yield source.pop()
        
        
for elt in get_random_without_repeats():
    print(elt)
```

You can add more sophisticated logic to regenerate the source after exhaustion, to suit your needs.
For instance, the following example shrinks the range of values from the bottom, every time the source is exhausted

```
import random


def get_random_without_repeats(n=8):
    source = []
    turn = 0
    while True:
        if not source:
            source = list(range(turn, n))
            if not source:
                return StopIteration
            turn += 1
            random.shuffle(source)
        yield source.pop()
        

for elt in get_random_without_repeats():
    print(elt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, you could just pull numbers from `random.sample` endlessly in a generator - they're guaranteed to never repeat, and if you iterate over an endless iterator like `itertools.cycle` you can have the pool of possible numbers "reset" once you've exhausted all numbers in the given range:

```
from itertools import islice

def get_numbers(minimum, maximum):
    # minimum and maximum are inclusive
    from itertools import cycle
    from random import sample
    for generator in cycle([sample]):
        yield from generator(range(minimum, maximum+1), k=maximum+1)


print(list(islice(get_numbers(0, 7), 16)))
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 4, 3, 7, 2, 6, 5, 1, 6, 0, 3, 7, 4, 5, 2]
```

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without using the built in itertools function? I don't think the problem allows it since I am supposed to construct my own class. Right now, I'm stuck on trying to add a range-changing function.